# TableLayout Android java set to full right?

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

```
public void responsePost(Editable editable)
    {
         TableLayout chatbox = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.chatbox);
         TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
         tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         TextView textview = new TextView(this);
         textview.setText(editable);
       //  textview.getTextColors(R.color.)
         textview.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

         tr1.addView(textview);
         chatbox.addView(tr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
         LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

           textview.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);    
    }
```

How can i make it go ALL THE WAY to the right? and not just a little bit? I used setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT) but that did not work.

[There is a picture of what it is doing.](http://i40.tinypic.com/5lou2o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need a little more detail, I couldn't duplicate your layout, what do you have in your main layout, and what code do you have in onCreate for the activity?

All you need is to set columns to stretchable:

```
chatbox.setColumnStretchable(1, true);
```

**and** you need one extra row, leave it blank

```
TextView col1 = new TextView(this);
col1.setText("");
tr1.addView(col1);
```

for example the complete code could be:

```
public class So extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); 

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // anonymous inner class
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
                Editable editable = editText1.getText();
                responsePost(editable);
                editText1.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    public void responsePost(Editable editable) {
        TableLayout chatbox = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.chatbox);
        TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
        // add these lines here
        TextView col1 = new TextView(this);
        col1.setText("");
        tr1.addView(col1);
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        textview.setText(editable);
        textview.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        tr1.addView(textview);
        // and this line
        chatbox.setColumnStretchable(1, true);
        chatbox.addView(tr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at the [tablelayout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html) and there is also a [relativeLayout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) too.

Comment: Mark, there is 2 things being drawn on there one being on the left and the other one will be on the right, so i need it in java code.

Comment: I got it to work, take a [look](http://i40.tinypic.com/vvq4p.png) and mark it answered if you're happy.

Comment: here are some more references to remind me and others
[common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html), 
[TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) and 
[TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)